# nuxt3 Pass props via router push

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

This worked ok in nuxt2

I think that in nuxt3, the props function mode of a route is ignored, or at least that's how it looks.

This is my code:

nuxt.config.ts

```
{
    hooks: {
    'pages:extend'(pages) {
      pages.push({
        name: 'test-admin',
        path: '/admin/users/teste',
        file: '~/pages/admin/users/test.vue',
        props: true,
      })
    },
  },
}
```

test.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ msg }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default defineNuxtComponent({
  name: 'test',
  props: {
    msg: {
      type: String,
      default: 'Hello world!',
    },
  },
})
</script>
```

how i trigger the navigation

```
const router = useRouter()
router.push({
    name: 'test-admin___en',
    props: { // or params: 
      msg: 'message from another page',
    },
})
```

I'm trying to have some data passed directly when navigating from a page to another one so I can directly display without having to call the api again and wait for it.
I have a /admin/users that lists all the users and then /admin/users/:id where i display data of one user.. I already have the data loaded in the list so I don't want to call the api again if I already have the data. This is what I'm trying to do.

for props, I tried the example that vue router has with function mode like this

```
{
    props: route => ({ msg: route.params.msg })
}
```

this doesn't work.. even if I return { msg: "some message" } it still doesn't work

the only way it works it this: (inside the route declaration)

```
{
    props: { msg: 'this message gets to the component' }
}
```

but this won't work because I cannot set hardcoded data there.. i need it to be dynamic

before anyone suggests it, I am trying to avoid implementing a workaround with store.

Comment: I'm interested in the same thing, but, at least accordingly to [this](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/discussions/16100#discussioncomment-4405660) answer, it is not currently possible, or at least it was not possible in Dec 2022.

Comment: @learntheropes thank you, i didn't find that issue.. will wait a bit longer but it seems i will have to do a workaround until we can have this as a feature

Answer (score 0):

#### Update: Page Meta instead of Props

In Nuxt3 I think the best solution to fit our needs is to use the route meta property. It permanently attaches values to the route.

In the `pages:extend` hook pass your custom properties to the `meta` parameter:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    hooks: {
        'pages:extend' (pages) {
            pages.push({
                path: '/my-pages-seo-url',
                name: 'my-page',
                meta: {
                    pageId: 'pass-some-id'
                },
                file: '~/pages/page.vue'
            })
        }
    },
});
```

You can access the route meta from every component, assuming you are in the given route (e.g. /my-pages-seo-url). I use the page component `/pages/page.vue` as an example for how to access the meta:

```js
<script setup>
    const route = useRoute()
    console.log(route.meta.pageId) // 'pass-some-id'
</script>
```

As this not requires workarounds it seems the best solution imo. If you are using nuxt-i18n the locale routes will generate like expected and they all provide the `pageId` from the route meta.

Hope that approach helps you.

#### Original answer

It would be nice if `NuxtPage` object accept `props` in the `pages:extend` hook. At this time it's possible to pass `props` withnin the `app/router.options.ts`:

```js
export default <RouterConfig> {
    routes: (_routes) => {
        _routes.push({
            name: 'my-page',
            path: '/my-page-seo-url',
            props: {
                id: <pass-some-id>,
            },
            component: () => import('~/pages/page.vue').then(r => r.default || r)
        })

        return _routes
    },
}
```

However, this workaround bring some bugs with routing when using nuxt-i18n. I guess because its called too late in the build process. Possible solution would be add the routes in `pages:extend` and then override them in `app/router.options.ts` to pass `props`. Seems like a big, wierd workaround. I try this out and update this answer if it works some kind of properbly.

Comment: this does not fit my needs... I want to be able to pass a custom id as prop when navigating to that route.. for example i want different "id" when navigating from page X than from Y

Comment: Yep, my bad. I understand your case wrong. it's not possible to pass dynamic "hidden" props to a component / page. To pass dynamic values on navigation (NuxtLink, navigateTo, router.push) you can only use `params` or `query`. Whats the downside of using params or query in your case?